# Can't trigger an event listener created through Plain JS with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created an event listener on the document using plain javascript. and I want to trigger that event using jQuery.

Reasons are essentially that I have one project written in plain JS and another written in jQuery.

```js
document.addEventListener('testEventName', function(event, data) {
  console.log('test event name was called.');
  alert(event.detail.test);
});

$(document).trigger('testEventName', {
  test: 'triggeredEvent'
});

// Create the event.
var event = new CustomEvent('testEventName', {
  detail: {
    test: 'customEvent'
  }
});
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z18dj3s9/1/

I can trigger the event using plain JavaScript, but I can't trigger it using `$(document).trigger`

Edit: Changed the output to an alert because it could overwrite.

Comment: @LukeStoward That's _precisely_ what OP did.

Comment: jQuery by design will generally only `trigger()` events that it has created. Some will work by proxy (such as `click`), however custom events, as in your case, will definitely not.

Comment: @msanford he implied he couldn't use JS because the project is written in jQuery. Last time I checked jQuery is JS.

Comment: Custom events: https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/

Comment: Why not just define that event handler function with a function label (not in-line), and then just call it from wherever you need, instead of creating events to trigger them to call the function?

Comment: *The trick is to add an `onxxxx` property to the element, where `xxxx` is the event name*

Comment: Interesting reading that appears to address this: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/wiki/jQuery-4.0-Event-Design

Comment: @LukeStoward You are incorrect, jQuery _is not_ JavaScript, jQuery is _written in_ JavaScript, which is materially different. See precisely the marked duplicate for one reason why (the fact that event handler binding works differently for jQuery (which is a library) objects and native events).